# package name not corresponding to file path?

Tags: android, google-maps

So while trying to copy the [google maps sample projects](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml), I kept getting an error on this line

```
package com.example.mapdemo;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Package name 'com.example.mapdemo' does not correspond to the file path 'com.example.myname.gps
```

I'm a relatively new programmer. If someone could explain what this error means, what caused it, and how I could fix it I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying a complete class from another project, make sure to change the package statement to match your own package name. I assume you need to change the first line of the class throwing the error for `package com.example.myname.gps`